# How to find class by function name in PHP class?

Tags: magento2, php, oop

For example I have a class **A** which extends class **B** and **B** extends **C** and so on.

Now I can get all the function which is accessible in class **A** by php function getClassMethods($this);

But if I found a function call in Class **A** like $this->someFunction(); and because of Abstraction, I unable to find in which class the someFuntion() is defined.

Is there any way to find this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you could do this using reflection. Here I have prepared a function for you to get the name of class from method name.

Approach 1:

```
function getMethodClassName($childClassName, $methodName)
{
    $class = new ReflectionClass($childClassName);
    $methods = $class->getMethods();
    foreach ($methods as $method)
    {
        if($method->getName() == $methodName){
            return $method->class;
        }

    }
    return null;
}
```

Approach 2(Credit @DavidManners ):

```
function getMethodClassName($childClassName, $methodName)
{   
    try{
        $class = new ReflectionClass($childClassName);
        $methodInfo = $class->getMethod($methodName);
        return $methodInfo->class;
    }catch(ReflectionException $e){
        return null;
    } 
}
```

Simply call this method

```
echo getMethodClassName(get_class($objC), "someFunction");
echo getMethodClassName("A", "someFunction");
```

Thanks & keep coding.

Comment: Oh very nice. I didn't know you could do that with the reflection class. One slight improvement is you could call `$class->getMethod($methodName)` rather than `getMethods()` then you do not have to loop over all methods as this could get messy with bigger classes.

Comment: Thanks @DavidManners, updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If this is just for you to have a look at classes when developing then I would suggest and IDE such as PHPStorm which has the option to show the structure of classes including all parent methods (see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/viewing-structure-of-a-source-file.html#).

But if you want to do this via code I think you would have to do something with `get_parent_class` and `get_class_methods`. I think you would need to recursively call `get_parent_class(ClassName::class)` down the class hierarchy while calling `get_class_methods` on the resulting class until you find the one without your method. Then the class will be defined in the last class to have this method in it.